# Count unique combinations of two columns

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

I have two rows, one for conduit number and one for conduit size. I need to find how many unique conduits there are for each conduit size.
starting table below

```
CN  CS
1   3/4
2   3/4
2   3/4
3   3/4
3   3/4
4   1/2
4   1/2
4   1/2
4   1/2
5   1/2
6   1
6   1
6   1
7   1
7   1
8   3/4
8   3/4
```

My expected is below:

```
cs    amount
3/4   4
1/2   2
1     2
```

I've tried many ways, but I can not seem to get it to work.

Comment: Use a pivot-table, it's what they are meant for. See the answer below to get the unique count. Also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62203122/9758194) post on SO.

Answer (score 2):

1. To get unique pairings:

   1. Go to **Data → Remove Duplicates**.
   2. Ensure both columns `CN` and `CS` are selected.
   3. Click **OK**.
2. From here, you have a list of unique combinations of conduit and size.  Next you need to sort by the size column:

   1. Go to **Data → Sort**.
   2. In the field **Column** select `CS`.
   3. In the field **Sort On** select `Values`.
   4. In the field **Order** select `A to Z`.
   5. Click **OK**.
   6. Click **OK**.
3. Then you run the count:

   1. Go to **Data → Outline → Subtotal**.
   2. In the field **At each change in:** select `CS`.
   3. In the field **Use function:** select `Count`
   4. Ensure **Replace current subtotals** and **Summary below data** are checked and **Page break between groups** is unchecked.
   5. Click **OK**.

Now you can copy out any cells you need from the generated data.

Additionally, if your data is not as ordered as your example, you can always **Data → Sort** by both `CN` and `CS` before you execute this procedure.

Answer (score 1):

To get unique value of CS, as Tripp Kinetics suggested, we could use **Remove Duplicates**.

Please copy the data of CS to other location, go to Data > select Remove Duplicates in Data tools group, then you will get the result as following.

[image]

To get the Amount of CS, we could use formulas, my is

```
=SUMPRODUCT((B$2:B$18=D2)*(1/COUNTIF(A$2:A$18,A$2:A$18)))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Absolute easiest is a pivot-table:

- Select your data
- Click tab `Insert` from the ribbon and choose `PivotTable`
- Choose where to insert the resulting table and check *"Add this data to the Data Model"*
- Use *"CS"* as column, and *"CN"* as values.
- Go to *"Value Field Settings"* and summarize values by *"Distinct Count"*
- Confirm and enjoy the resulting table:

Answer (score 0):

Good Day Dan,

Things are being a bit picky today, but this page should help. I can/'t get the sum to work with one formula in one cell for some reason.

[enter link description here](https://www.get-digital-help.com/count-unique-distinct-values-that-meet-multiple-criteria-in-excel/)

But this screen cap might get you started as well.  The text version of the formulas are what is in the cell below.   The formula in D4 is the same in all cells below, while the other two columns update depending on the row they are in.

[image]

Hope this helps